# hreflang tags in DNN

Tags: dnn9

I want to have hreflang tags in the source code of a website, created in DNN

I have a website that is multilingual. In order to get a correct mapping for each language a correct hreflang should be present in the head (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en). As you can/have to appoint localized versions of the DNN to a language, I expect that the appropriate hreflang tags are placed. But in the code there is nothing.

I can not imagine that I am the first one encountering the problem. So...how did you solve it? Code or setting?

Answer (score 0):

Tycho,

I agree, there should be a hreflang tag, as it could be easily automated. At the moment I only see the possibility to add a page setting (Advanced :: S.E.O. :: Page header tags).

Maybe opening an issue or delivering a pull request could solve the problem - but it seems you have already [done this](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/issues/2819).

Happy DNNing!
Michael